# create sub reports in an empty main report (just as container for sub reports to display)

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I want to create an empty main report in Jasper Studio  to display existing reports as multiple sub reports in it. The main report should just act as a container to display multiple sub reports.
How do I proceed?

Comment: Create it, included the subreport or in detail band (passing JREmptyDatasrouce(1) or in title band... this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979397/create-consecutive-tables-in-jaspersoft/34990092#34990092

Comment: Can you guide me stepwise procedure to create one? I have tried refering diff documents but couldnt find one with empty main report and existing sub reports. I am getting error as new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExressionEvalException:Error evaluating source text

Comment: Sorry I am very bad at editing. I am getting an empty report on running the jrxml. Though if I double click on sub report in main report in summary band the sub report can be viewed.So the path given works.But main report in whole doesnt work. Anything wrong in property in main report  given for sub report expression and data source expression?

Comment: 1) You do not need to query in your main report (leave query empty empty) and set attribute whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" see example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281933/why-bother-creating-the-first-dataset-when-using-table-component/35290269#35290269

Comment: 2) Test that both the subreport are working passing the connection and correct parameter, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865347/subreport-not-shown/34872897#34872897

Comment: 3) Put the subreport side by side remember to set correct width in subreport

Comment: Hurrah !! @Petter I got it. But facing alignment issues. Trying to align 4 sub reports into one Title band. 2 up and 2 below them. Do you mean to say to keep the report page width same as sum of the upper 2 sub report widths?

Comment: if you include a subreport and set width = 100 the subreport page width should be 100... that's what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I created an empty main report with select * from TABLE query without reading fields done ok. Then added a new sub report to summary Band .In the main report added sub report property as Expression:"subreport1.jrxml" and Connection property turns to $P{Report_Connection}. Run the report I got the chart displayed in main report.

Comment: You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35402912/edit) your question, since this ends with another question.